# Pasar un Array mediante un POST usando JavaScript o jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo un **array** que quiero pasar `mediante un POST` (usando el `$.post` de `jQuery`):

```
var linkNamesList = []; // A este array se le añaden elementos al usar la web

function sendData() {
    $.post('create_paste.php', {
        "linkNames": linkNamesList, //ESTE ES EL ARRAY, PERO PARECE QUE ASÍ DIRECTO NO FUNCIONA
        "name": title
    },function(data) {
        console.log('¡Hecho!', data);
    });
}
```

Cuando el array se lee en PHP, **obtengo una variable vacía**. Me gustaría hacerlo sin PHP, porque con PHP ya sé que está el `serialize`, que seguramente funcione.

Comment: haz una prueba con `"linkNames": ["a","b","c"]` y ve si recibes el dato, no deberias tener problemas recibiendo el array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cuando se envían datos mediante una petición `POST`, tienen que ser cadena para eso tienes que utilizar `JSON.stringify()`

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_stringify.asp

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var obj = [{ name: "Euler", age: 25, city: "Lima" },{ name: "Diego", age: 25, city: "Tarapoto" }];
var myJSON = JSON.stringify(obj);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myJSON;
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

lo que se enviara sera lo siguiente :

> [{"name":"Euler","age":25,"city":"Lima"},{"name":"Diego","age":25,"city":"Tarapoto"}]

para tu caso quedaría así el `javascript`

```
var linkNamesList = ["dato1", "dato2", "dato3","dato4"]; 

function sendData() {
    $.post('create_paste.php', {
        "linkNames": JSON.stringify(linkNamesList), 
        "name": title
    },function(data) {
        console.log('¡Hecho!', data);
    });
}
```

Espero te ayude, saludos.

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que no estás mandando un array, en la documentación de jquery https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/
tiene este ejemplo:

```
$.post( "test.php", { 'choices[]': [ "Jon", "Susan" ] } );
```

y es correcto lo que estás haciendo sin embargo tu array está vacío(no sé si lo llenas en algún otro momento), pero podrías probar con esto:

```
var linkNamesList = ["nombre 1", "nombre 2", "nombre 3"]; // A este array se le añaden elementos al usar la web

function sendData() {
    $.post('create_paste.php', {
        "linkNames": linkNamesList, //ESTE ES EL ARRAY, PERO PARECE QUE ASÍ DIRECTO NO FUNCIONA
        "name": title
    },function(data) {
        console.log('¡Hecho!', data);
    });
}
```